# KeePass from Application Center just plain doesn't work

Tags: applications

I know it's a uncurated app so I don't really expect this question to be answered, but the fact of the matter is I just installed KeePass from the Application Center, created a database with just a Master Password (no KeyFile) containing just one entry, saved it on the system disk, closed it (for some reason it insisted on saving it again even though I hadn't touched it since the first save), and then couldn't open it again (database corrupted or password wrong).

On checking the GitHub repository I found that this "issue" (astonishingly embarrassing blunder I would call it) was fixed in KeePass 2.2.4, and the Application Center had given me 2.0.3. So I deleted it, went to apt-cache search and found no less than 3 versions available: keypass2, keypassx & keypassxc. Comments on AskUbuntu by a more diligent user than me however indicated that only the latter was still being updated regularly, so I installed it and it works.

Bottom line: Uncurated is one thing, but totally untested is quite another, and now I'm no longer sure that I can trust any uncurated apps from the Application Center. That is really not acceptable!

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to replicate this issue following your steps in the first paragraph. Is it KeePass or KeePassX? I found KeePassX and KeePassXC in the AppCenter and neither seemed to have the issue, although maybe there is a particular setup this happens with.

To your more general question, while I can't speak for elementary, this appears to be exactly what they mean by "uncurated" (note the "It may not receive bug fix or feature updates" warning when installing one), and they don't appear to spend time on checking uncurated apps for issues/upgrades between bi-annual releases. I don't believe you are expected to trust the uncurated apps; trust in the curated apps, sideload or install uncurated where you feel you can and want to invest the research necessary.

Comment: KeePassX is version 2.0.3 while KeyPassXC is 2.5.1, which is consistent with the latter being the only one currently being kept up to date; the former is the one I had problems with. I find it a bit strange that KeyPassXC shows up in the AppCenter as installed even though I installed it using apt-get; how are these two managers connected? Don't know how the folks at Elementary decide what to put on the list of uncurated apps, but I don't think they're helping their users by including out-of-dated unsupported software on it. Just sayin' ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't install uncurated stuff from the appcenter, I use apt for that most of the time. I think the uncurated apps are just tons of stuff that works with ubuntu.

I use apt to install any app that is not made for elementary specifically and I also still update via the command line. While I see that Elementary is doing a better job at GUI only then most distros and I think that it is one of the few that can be run GUI everything is just a tat more reliable in the command line.